# Resource file variable giving string ASCII code issues in js alert box

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, resource-files

I have a variable in a resource file (.resx), the value having the word `you'd`.

When I try to use this variable directly in an alert box it displays `you'd` as `you&#39;d`.

What could be the issue? and how do I resolve it?

Comment: sorry, I meant ASCII code

Comment: This has nothing to do with the character encoding (UTF-8/ASCII), but is simply a matter of a value that has a “special character” written as a numeric HTML entity – in a context where this is not evaluated back to an actual character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

alert('@System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("Hello, You'd like this.")');