# Change label text from .resx, issue with especial character

Tags: javascript, html, ascii, special-characters, globalization

I'm trying to change the text property from a label dynamically. I get the new value from a .resx file, this new value contains the characters Nº, but it doesn't display correctly, instead Nº it displays N&#186. 
I tried some advises that I found here on the stackoverflow, like [Resource file variable giving string ASCII code issues in js alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919697/resource-file-variable-giving-string-ascii-code-issues-in-js-alert-box)

I also tried to use javascript encode/decode functions, but none of them worked. I'm spending a lot of time trying to fix it. Please, any help?

Its a MVC3 application. My code:

```
  novoLabel = "@Label.LblPares";

 $("label[for='Cabo_Pares']").text(novoLabel);
```

@Label.LblPares value is Nº de Pares and its displays to the user the value N&#186 de Pares

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaning text() to html():

```
$("label[for='Cabo_Pares']").html(novoLabel);
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AWzSc/